# Dynamically allocatable array

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

I want to know the difference between

```
int *pia=new int[10];
```

and

```
int *pis=new int[10]();
```

In other words, I want to know what is in the pia when it is not initialized but has been allocated memory space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first specifies *default initialisation*; for simple types like `int`, this means there is no initialisation and they have unspecified values.

The second specifies *value initialisation*; for simple types like `int`, this means they are initialised with a value of zero.

Comment: Does the newer uniform initialisation syntax `int *pis=new int[10]{};` also work in this case?

Comment: @Niall: Yes, that also gives value initialisation.